# Checking if form is filled and giving a message

Tags: php, web

If name, gender or dorm is not submitted by the user, the page should give an error in red on pressing the "Register" button. This is my code but it is not working well. Its ALWAYS giving the error to the user.

```
<?php 
//checking if submitted

if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{
    if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["gender"]) || empty($_POST["dorm"]))
        $error=true;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Fresh IMs</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <h1>Register for Fresh IMs</h1>
            <br/><br/>
            <? if(isset($error)): ?>
                <div style="color:red"> You must fill out the form!</div>
            <? endif ?>
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <table style="border:0; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <td><input name="name" type="text"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Captain:</td>
                        <td><input name="captain" type="checkbox"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Gender:</td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="gender" type="radio" value="F">F
                            <input name="gender" type="radio" value="M">M
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Dorm:</td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="dorm">
                                <option value="" ></option>
                                <option value="Apply court" >Apply Court</option>
                                <option value="Candy">Candy</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input name="action" type="submit" value="Register">
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is this code written on index.php?

Comment: <? if(isset($error)): ?> use <?php if(isset($error)):?>

Comment: @DS9  "You must fill out the form!" <- this line is always visible to the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is should be this one You Missed the `php tag`

```
<?php if (isset($error)): ?>
                <div style="color:red"> You must fill out the form!</div>
                <?php endif ?>
```

Try this it may works

Thanks

Comment: Glad to know your Problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the `empty` function with `isset` function